# How to redirect from FormView to a ListView after form validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-validation

In my Django application, I would like to display a form where a user enters a name to search for `Person`s from an external data source (not model). I am using class-based generic views and have a working application (code attached below) with a minor inconvenience - I would like to see if there is a better way to do this.

First, here's how I have done it:

1. I have a `Form` with 3 fields (first, second and last name) and a `clean()` where I check if at least one field is populated
2. A `FormView` which renders this form, and `form_valid()` method which does nothing at the moment (reasons will become clear shortly)
3. An entry in `urls.py` to render this view and display the form in a template. The form is being submitted to a ListView with `GET`, and not the FormView itself (sad!)
4. A `ListView` where I define `get_queryset(self)` because data comes from an external source, not a Model; and I use `self.request.GET.get('first_name', '')` etc. to retrieve query string values, make a connection to the external data source and get a Pandas dataframe which I convert to a list of records and render, paginated, in the template.
5. An entry in `urls.py` for the List View and render the template of search results.

Everything works but, hopefully, the problem is apparent. The FormView is being used only to display the form, but the form submits to the ListView where data is retrieved to be displayed. This means that my  `form_valid()` in the FormView and consequently `clean()` from the form aren't even used - I can work around it by using Javascript based validation but I would like to be able to use the FormView to its full potential.

**So, how do I redirect to ListView with the form input, after form validation?**

Here's my simple, and working, code:

**urls.py**

```
...
path('search/name', form_views.NameSearchView.as_view(), name='search-name'),
path('search/results', list_views.SearchResultsList.as_view(), name='search-results'),
...
```

**forms.py**

```
class NameSearchForm(forms.Form):
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', required=False)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', required=False)
    second_name = forms.CharField(label='Second Name', required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        first_name = cleaned_data['first_name'].strip()
        second_name = cleaned_data['second_name'].strip()
        last_name = cleaned_data['last_name'].strip()
        # At least one field should be filled to search
        if not (first_name or second_name or last_name):
            raise ValidationError(
                _('Fill in a name to search!'),
                code='invalid',
                params={
                    'first_name': first_name,
                    'second_name': second_name,
                    'last_name': last_name,
                })
```

**form_views.py**

```
class NameSearchView(FormView):
    template_name = 'app/search_name.html'
    form_class = NameSearchForm
    
    # This is clearly wrong as it does nothing
    success_url = '.'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.form = form
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

**list_views.py**

```
class SearchResultsList(ListView):
    template_name = 'app/search_results.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        first_name = self.request.GET.get('first_name', '').strip()
        second_name = self.request.GET.get('second_name', '').strip()
        last_name = self.request.GET.get('last_name', '').strip()

        conn = create_connection() # This abstraction creates a database connection
        query = '''
        SELECT i.first_name first_name,
               i.second_name second_name,
               i.last_name last_name,
               i.info
          FROM db.person_tbl i
         WHERE i.name_type = 'primary'
        '''

        params = []
        terms = [first_name, second_name, last_name]
        term_keys = ['first', 'sec', 'last']

        for i, term in enumerate(terms):
            if term:
                query += f' AND i.srch_{term_keys[i]}_name = ?'
                params.append(term)

        # this abstraction gets the pandas dataframe
        object_list = conn.get_data(query, params=params)\
            .sort_values(by='last_name')\
            .to_dict('records')

        return object_list
```

I would like to be able to submit `POST` to the FormView itself, validate the form and then display the search results, paginated, through a ListView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can change the [get_success_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) method or properly set the success_url attribute

Comment: @Mugoma - that was my first thought as well, but if I try changing that to reverse('search-results') I get an error: `raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'your_app.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`

I checked to ensure there are no circular imports but I don't see any, so I am not sure what's going wrong, and hence the question. Any pointers to resolve this would be great!

Comment: Try using underscore instead of hyphen in the url name